# How can define RadioButtons with GroupName in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I need some RadioButtons that grouped together in one of view page at mvc project this is a part of my view code:

```
<body>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>"   
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>PhoneNumber</legend>
    <div class="Radio" runat="server">
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="MyG" ID="RadioButton1" Text="RadioText1" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tel1) %>
    </div>
......

<div class="Radio" runat="server">
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="MyG" ID="RadioButton2" Text="RadioText2" />
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tel3) %>
    </div>

.......
```

when define RadioButtons as above there is an error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Control 'RadioButton1' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

How can I add `runat = server` to `Html.BeginForm()` or any other way to add grouped RadioButtons to view of mvc??

How about Razor view?? is there any way to define grouped RadioButtons in RazorView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input  type="radio" id="SelectedPlanType" name="Plan1" value='1'>
```

Radiobuttons can be grouped under a common name.

Comment: just use   <input type="radio" id="RadioButton1"  name="MyG" value='1'>

Comment: foreach (var item2 in Model.HavingPlans)                                                                     {
 <b> <input  type="radio" id="SelectedPlanType"  name="Plan1" value='@item2.Id' >                                                                                         @item2.Price.ToString("0.00")                                                                                                  @item2.Currency.CurrencyCode                                                                                              </b>
}

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you should not use WebForms's** `<asp:RadioButton />` controls. Instead, you should just output the radio buttons (by writing the HTML code either yourself or using the existing `HtmlHelper` helper methods) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, avoid using older style webform controls and where possible try to use strongly bound MVC controls.

The *group* name will be figured out by mvc using (typically) the property name of your model

so in Razor:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsATallPerson, "True")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsATallPerson, "False")
```

And in Aspx:

```
<% Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsATallPerson, "True") %>
<% Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsATallPerson, "False") %>
```

In this crude example, my model contains a bool? (IsATallPerson) that will dive my radio button.

m => m.IsATallPerson binds the model property to a control

The string "True" or "False" dives weather the radio button is selected.

Everything else should just work out of the box in terms of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

The format should be `@Html.RadioButtonFor(the Property that saves the selected value,Value) Text To be Shown`. Example:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsATallPerson, "True") @model.Tel1
```